# How to Store 2 analogRead values and read using EEPROM for Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, analogread, eeprom

Trying to write 2 values coming from `analogread(A0)` and `analogread(A1)` by `EEPROM.write`  and retrieve the values by `EEPROM.read`. I tried the following sketch for each write and read. However, could not get the values. Any help please.

For writing to EEPROM:

```
#include <EEPROMex.h>
int addr = 0;
int array[] = {0, 0};
char a;
void setup() {
}
void loop() {
    array[0] = analogRead(0) / 4;
    array[1] = analogRead(1) / 4;
    EEPROM.write(addr, a);
    addr = addr + 1;

    if (addr == 512) {
        addr = 0;
    }

    delay(100);
}
```

For reading from EEPROM is:

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
int address = 0;
int value[2];
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    while (!Serial) {
        ;
    }
}
void loop() {
    value = EEPROM.read(address);
    Serial.print(address);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(value[0]);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(value[1]);
    Serial.println();
    address = address + 1;

    if (address == 512) {
        address == 0;
    }

    delay(500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Reading and Writing Data Structures to EEPROM](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/EEPROMWriteAnything).

```C++
EEPROM.write(addr,a);
```

You can't *directly* write arrays. See the link for how to do it.

Example code:

```C++
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <EEPROMAnything.h>

int array[2];
int addr=0;

void setup()
{  
}

void loop()
{
  array[0] = analogRead(0)/4;
  array[1] = analogRead(1)/4; 
  EEPROM_writeAnything(addr, array);
  addr += sizeof (array);

  if(addr >= 512)
    exit (1);

  delay(100);
}
```

Your posted code is a bit flawed anyway. You know EEPROM has a limited life? If you have a sketch that writes to EEPROM indefinitely you will wear it out.

My code above stops once it reaches address 512.

Answer (score 0):

You write the read value directly to `value`, while value is actually and array. Try this instead.

```
void loop() {
    value[0] = EEPROM.read(address);
    value[1] = EEPROM.read(address + 1);
    Serial.print(address);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(value[0]);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(value[1]);
    Serial.println();
    address = address + 2;

    if (address == 512) {
        address = 0;
    } // not address==0;

    delay(500);
}
```

Comment: If this fails try `EEPROM.write(&addr,a);` and `EEPROM.read(&address);`

Comment: `address==0;` ?

Comment: @NickGammon missed that one. Nice catch.

Comment: cant do anything with EEPROM_writeAnything.

Comment: I tried with EEPROM_writeAnything but only get one analogread output data. What should I do? Apparently I try to write 2 sensors voltage output in an experiment and then retrieve the stored values for data analysis.

Comment: I think these comments are targeted at @NickGammon answer, not mine.

Comment: `What should I do?` - you should amend your question, and post the code you tried.

Comment: An `int` is two bytes so you should be doubling your address increases, n'est pas?

Comment: @CharlieHanson `address = address + 2;`?

Comment: The OP uses an `int` array yet stores only the lowest significant byte into the EEPROM. Bad practice but goes unnoticed because the maximum value ever stored is only 255 (MAX_ADC / 4). The uninitiated could be misled into thinking one call each to `EEPROM.write()` and `EEPROM.read()` will magically store and retrieve a multibyte value. In hindsight my comment should have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

EEPROM can store one byte at a location. To store value of int, it requires two consecutive location. For double, it requires four memory location. I have written code to store and read, int & double to and from built-in EEPROM. Modify as per your need.

```
/*
  StackExchange Question: "How to Store 2 analogRead values and read using EEPROM for Arduino uno?"
  Question Id: 15910 (http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/15910/how-to-store-2-analogread-values-and-read-using-eeprom-for-arduino-uno)
  Author: Anurag S. Vasanwala (AnuragVasanwala@gmail.com)

  Tested on Arduino Version 1.6.7

  Description:  This sketch helps to store and read, Integer & Double to and from built-in EEPROM.
  Objectives:
    + Write Integer @ Specified Address (Fn: EEPROM_Write_Int)
      + Conversion from Integer to Byte Array
      + Store Bytes
    + Read Integer from Specified Address (Fn: EEPROM_Read_Int)
      + Read Bytes
      + Conversion from Byte Array to Integer
    + Write Double @ Specified Address (Fn: EEPROM_Write_Double)
      + Conversion from Double to Byte Array
      + Store Bytes
    + Read Double from Specified Address (Fn: EEPROM_Read_Double)
      + Read Bytes
      + Conversion from Byte Array to Double
 */
#include <EEPROM.h>

// MACRO : Combines FROM_BYTES into TO_OBJECT of datatype "DATATYPE"
#define CombineBytes(FROM_BYTES, DATATYPE, TO_OBJECT) \
  TO_OBJECT = *((DATATYPE *)FROM_BYTES);

// MACRO : Splits FROM_DATA of DATATYPE into equivalent byte array TO_BYTES
#define GetBytes(FROM_DATA, DATATYPE, TO_BYTES) \
  *((DATATYPE *)TO_BYTES) = FROM_DATA;

// Writes Integer's equivalent bytes to Address and Address + 1
void EEPROM_Write_Int(unsigned int Address, int Data)
{
  // Get the size of datatype to write number of bytes
  const byte SizeOf_DataType = sizeof(int);

  // Create tem buffer to get Bytes of Datatype
  byte Temp_Buffer[SizeOf_DataType];

  // Call macro to store byte array into Temp_Buffer from Data
  GetBytes(Data, int, Temp_Buffer);

  // Write number of bytes to memory location specified in Address and so on
  for(byte Index = 0; Index < SizeOf_DataType; Index++)
  {
    EEPROM.write(Address + Index, Temp_Buffer[Index]);
  }
}

// Reads two bytes from Address and Address + 1 and returns equivalent int
int EEPROM_Read_Int(unsigned int Address)
{
  // Get the size of datatype to write number of bytes
  const byte SizeOf_DataType = sizeof(int);

  // Create tem buffer to get Bytes of Datatype
  byte Temp_Buffer[SizeOf_DataType];

  int Result;

  // Read number of bytes from memory location
  for(byte Index = 0; Index < SizeOf_DataType; Index++)
  {
    Temp_Buffer[Index] = EEPROM.read(Address + Index);
  }

  // Call macro to combine bytes into equivalent to int
  CombineBytes(Temp_Buffer, int, Result);

  return Result;
}

// Writes Double's equivalent bytes to Address, Address + 1, Address + 2 and Address + 3
void EEPROM_Write_Double(unsigned int Address, double Data)
{
  // Get the size of datatype to write number of bytes
  const byte SizeOf_DataType = sizeof(double);

  // Create tem buffer to get Bytes of Datatype
  byte Temp_Buffer[SizeOf_DataType];

  // Call macro to store byte array into Temp_Buffer from Data
  GetBytes(Data, double, Temp_Buffer);

  // Write number of bytes to memory location specified in Address and so on
  for(byte Index = 0; Index < SizeOf_DataType; Index++)
  {
    EEPROM.write(Address + Index, Temp_Buffer[Index]);
  }
}

// Reads four bytes from Address, Address + 1, Address + 2 and Address + 3 and returns equivalent double
double EEPROM_Read_Double(unsigned int Address)
{
  // Get the size of datatype to write number of bytes
  const byte SizeOf_DataType = sizeof(double);

  // Create tem buffer to get Bytes of Datatype
  byte Temp_Buffer[SizeOf_DataType];

  double Result;

  // Read number of bytes from memory location
  for(byte Index = 0; Index < SizeOf_DataType; Index++)
  {
    Temp_Buffer[Index] = EEPROM.read(Address + Index);
  }

  // Call macro to combine bytes into equivalent to double
  CombineBytes(Temp_Buffer, double, Result);

  return Result;
}


void setup()
{
  // Initialize Serial @ 9600 baud
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Print size of datatype just for reference
  /* Serial.print("Size of byte = ");
  Serial.println(sizeof(byte));
  Serial.print("Size of int = ");
  Serial.println(sizeof(int));
  Serial.print("Size of float = ");
  Serial.println(sizeof(float));
  Serial.print("Size of double = ");
  Serial.println(sizeof(double)); */

  int myInt1 = -290;
  int myInt2;
  double myDbl1 = 23.41;
  double myDbl2;

  // Write myInt1 @ 100 memory location; It requires 2 consequtive memory location to store integer
  EEPROM_Write_Int(100, myInt1);

  // Read integer located @ memory location 100 and assign it to myInt2
  myInt2 = EEPROM_Read_Int(100);
  Serial.println(myInt2);

  // Write myInt1 @ 200 memory location; it requires 4 consequtive memory location to store double
  EEPROM_Write_Double(200, myDbl1);

  // Read double located @ memory location 200 and assign it to myDbl2
  myDbl2 = EEPROM_Read_Double(200);  
  Serial.println(myDbl2);
}

void loop()
{

}
```

> This code is successfully tested on Arduino Version "1.6.7".